# Genymotion in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, genymotion

My Eclipse can't find my `Genymotion`, the genymotion doesn't appear, what's the problem?
I receive an error exception:

```
 (VBoxManage): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Genymobile/reg": CreateProcess error=2
```

The system cannot find the file specified when I try to run genymotion eclipse plugin. What is wrong? I am using x64 windows 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install install Genymotion plugin for Eclipse:
In Eclipse, go to Help > Install new software and click Add.
Fill in the fields with Genymotion name and http://plugins.genymotion.com/eclipse/ location.
Under Genymobile, check Genymotion and Genymotion Eclipse Tools and follow the steps indicated by Eclipse.
You can Find help from following link [genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download)